# NPM Start – Permission Error

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line, npm

I got an error when I try to run "npm start". Seems like I have some permission issues, but I have no clue how to fix it and I've probably messed up things... So I would preferably delete Node and NPM and everything else that could cause problems...

This is the error I get. Maybe someone can help... Thanks in advance!

```
npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/thomasveit/quickstart
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 

error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.js': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.js'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.js.map'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.spec.js': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.spec.js'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.spec.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.component.spec.js.map'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.module.js': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.module.js'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.module.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/app.module.js.map'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/main.js': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/main.js'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/main.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/app/main.js.map'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/e2e/app.e2e-spec.js': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/e2e/app.e2e-spec.js'
error TS5033: Could not write file '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/e2e/app.e2e-spec.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/e2e/app.e2e-spec.js.map'
app/app.component.spec.ts(4,50): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(5,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(6,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(9,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(14,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(21,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(27,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(27,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(29,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(32,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
app/app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
app/app.module.ts(1,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
app/app.module.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
app/main.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(1,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(3,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(7,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(11,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.884692043
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.884692043'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.884692043'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.884692043' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/thomasveit/quickstart/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a permissions issue with the directory in which you set up your project.  I think you need to update the permissions to allow writing to:
/Users/thomasveit/quickstart/

The easiest thing might be to create a new directory, since this one might be a bit broken. Set permissions (recursively) wide-open, and then copy everything to the new location before trying to run things again.  Or, you can try the same on the current directory.

You can set permissions on the folder via Windows Explorer if you want, via:
right-click the folder --> Properties --> Security Tab
Click the check box in the lower left to *Replace all child permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object*

Or, your can do command line on the folder, something like this might work:
icacls "C:\Users\thomasveit\quickstart\" /t /g

If you are trying to figure out what might be causing the issue, you could also try "npm run lite" to see if the server can get going?  Rather than run the concurrent commands in the *npm start* which adds more potential for confusion over an error.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a copy of your package.json file? Because it looks like, as if you didn't set up something correctly there.

Comment: it's exactly this one from the angular quickstart project: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json

i haven't changed anything...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! I did an npm clean cache and installed node 7.1.0 and then it worked again...

Answer (score 0):

I went to each file listed in the error, right-clicked on it in the File Explorer, and changed it's permissions. The error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I had an equally named file (e.g.: ./dist) at the same location to one of the required directories typcript tries to create. 
For instance, once I switched in my typscriptconfig.json the setting outFile: "dist" to outDir: "dist" and then I run into exactly the same problem. 
After deleting the file dist, everything was fine again.
Conclusion: look at files having the same name and location as one of the required typescript folders and delete/rename those.